# When is the Gramian matrix of the frame an identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I have read that Gramian matrix of any orthonormal basis is an identity matrix https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix. I wanted to know if we can obtain an idetity matrix in the case of frame(Gabor) as well. If yes, what are the conditions on frames (dual/tight)?

Comment: Maybe try to decide it is an identity matrix and see what it leads to?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The Gramian matrix of the fram is the identity matrix if and only if the frame is an orthonormal basis. Or do I miss something?